# Storing binary into BLOB

Tags: java, oracle, spring, stored-procedures, oracle10g

I have to use a store procedure via an Oracle DB.

I used spring to call it

```
public StoreOperation(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate) {
  super(jdbcTemplate, STORE);
  declareParameter(new SqlParameter("in_binary_data", Types.BINARY));
  //declareParameter(new SqlParameter("in_binary_data", OracleTypes.BLOB));
  declareParameter(new SqlParameter("in_int_id", Types.INTEGER));
  declareParameter(new SqlOutParameter("out_int_id", Types.BIGINT));
  declareParameter(new SqlOutParameter("out_checksum", Types.VARCHAR));
  compile();
}

public Map execute(byte[] signedPdf, Long intId) {
  Map inParams = new HashMap(2);
  inParams.put("in_binary_data", signedPdf);
  inParams.put("in_int_id", intId);
  return execute(inParams);
}
```

Apparenlty using Types.BINARY works

```
declareParameter(new SqlParameter("in_binary_data", Types.BINARY));
```

Using BLOB does not allow

```
declareParameter(new SqlParameter("in_binary_data", Types.BLOB));
```

==> java.lang.ClassCastException: [B cannot be cast to oracle.sql.BFILE]]

It is a legacy stored procedure so i do not have access to the Blob to stream to it so I am forced to use byte[]

It might be a problem if the sql type i use is Types.BINARY and the database type is BLOB ?

So storing a byte[] in a BLOB without using the java.sql.types.Blob and streaming is ok ?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. The datatype `oracle.sql.BFILE`  is not the same as `oracle.sql.BLOB` (for which setting `Type.BLOB` will work). [Check this](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/java.102/b16018/typesupp.htm).
2. Your are trying to save Type.BLOB into a field of type `BFILE` and hence the casting that driver is trying to do is failing. ( *java.lang.ClassCastException: [B cannot be cast to oracle.sql.BFILE]]*)
3. IMHO, the approach you have taken seems valid. A `byte[]` is safe to cast in a Binary File (`BFILE`)
4. Please also try using oracle specific type `oracle.jdbc.OracleTypes.BFILE` (*This class is bundled with driver jar*) instead of `java.sql.BLOB`.(*I am not sure how spring will handle this*)

Additionally, please [check this link](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/java.111/b31224/oralob.htm#i1059941) and ([this as well](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/java.920/a96654/oralob.htm#1059942) )for dealing with BFILE types. This involves using Oracle specific class.

Comment: I get byte[] and i pass this to the stored procedure that uses BLOB as type to store